# FindAll multiple conditions

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to use FindAll to return a list of objects that match. It works great when I only use one condition, for example

```
patientstatus = statuslist.FindAll(delegate(StatusReader.onestatus p1)
{
   return p1.WL_ID == patlist[i].wl_id;
});
```

But I would like to use multiple conditions, some of which contain if statements and I can't figure out how. It seems like the format needs to have a return statement, and the example from Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) only uses one condition.

I could either have multiple FindAll methods for each condition, or just make a loop that scans through all the values myself, but there's got to be an obvious thing I'm missing, right?

Comment: A delegate body may contain multiple statements; e.g. `if (p1.PropertyXYZ == 17) return false; return p1.WL_ID == patlist[i].wl_id;`

Comment: oops sorry, meant if statements haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what "if loops" are, but you can always just stitch them together:

```
patientstatus = statuslist.FindAll(delegate(StatusReader.onestatus p1)
{
   if(p1.WL_ID != patlist[i].wl_id)
       return false;

   if(otherStuff != 5)
       return false;

   for(var x in p1.stuff)
       if(x == 7)
           return false;

   return true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var patientStatus = statusList.Where(p => p
{
    // Put in logic here as you need
    return p.WL_ID == patlist[i].wl_id || p.YourSecondProperty == WhateverYouWantToCheck;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think about something like

```
public abstract class Condition
{
    public abstract bool Sutisfied(StatusReader.onestatus status);
}

public class Condition1 : Condition
{
   public override bool Sutisfied(StatusReader.onestatus status)  {

      //check for something and return 
   }
}

public class Condition2 : Condition
{
   public override bool Sutisfied(StatusReader.onestatus status)  {

      //check for something and return 
   }
}
```

After can have a list of conditions, like

```
List<Condition> conditions = 
     new List<Condition>{new Conditon1(), new Condition2()}
```

and after *this* list use inside

```
patientstatus = statuslist.FindAll(delegate(StatusReader.onestatus status)
{
    return conditions.TrueForAll(c=>c.Sutisfied(status));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your delegate simply needs to return true for a match to your conditions and false for a non-match to your conditions.  It doesn't have to be a single line return statement.  You can create boolean values, have if statements, for loops, and anything else you want in your delegate - so long as it returns true or false along all code paths.

So you can do as many if statements or loops as you want.

If you really want to maintain it as one line, you can do something like the following...

```
return (condition1 == condition1) || (condition2 == condition2) || (condition3 == condition3);
```